# Data Compression algorithm

Tags: c#

I need an alogorihtm to store credit card data in reduced format [less memory].
For eg:-to store following number as 
12345665
12345777
12456666
12458888

as
12345 
          665 777
1245
       6666 8888
Is there any algorithm to find out best storage group?

Comment: Why are you not encrypting the Credit Card data / holding it (only if you must) in a PCI compliant manner?

Comment: With all respect, but that is crap. Even with 10 million cards it is not worth it to store the individual cards compressed. Put them in a database, let the database handle the work. IF (!) you are even allowed to store them (hint: your contracts with the CC company may tell you NOT to do that).

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) Data Structure.

Comment: +1, a trie is similar to what Samjog is trying to show with the string suffix 'compression'.  But the right answer is to not store credit card numbers at all.  If these were any other kind of number, the right answer would be store them normally and then tell the database to do compression for you.

Comment: That's a good point:) One should not be storing such information in the first place in the manner described. Other than that, what Samjog wants to achieve can be done by Tries irrespective of what is actually being represented.